# modalviewcontroller animation too fast?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm displaying a modal uiviewcontroller in the normal fashion:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.lvc animated:YES];
//do stuff
```

and later on...

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
```

The problem is that //do stuff is too fast, and the dismiss call happens before the presentation call animation completes, which has the net effect of not dismissing the view at all.  if i set the animation parameter to false, everything works, every time, or if //do stuff takes longer than the animation...

what to do? sleep? (ick), cancel the transition animation somehow?

not enough info? here's some more:

the point is, sometimes the worker thread finishes *before* the original modalviewcontroller *animation* completes, which causes problems when dismissmodalviewcontroller is called. In summary, if you call dismiss before the present animation completes, you cannot actually dismiss it. I'm filing a bug w/ apple atm.

And here's the proof testcase:

```
#import "ModalbugsViewController.h"

@implementation modalbugsViewController
@synthesize modal;
-(void)dismisser {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
-(void) sleeper:(NSNumber *) t{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:[t floatValue]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismisser) withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:TRUE];
}
-(IBAction) shortClick:(id)sender {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.modal animated:YES];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sleeper:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1f]];

}
-(IBAction) longClick:(id)sender {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.modal animated:YES];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sleeper:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f]];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [self.modal release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to provide more information as to what you're trying to achieve. Is the modal view being used a Please Wait dialogue (as lyonanderson suggests)? If so, why do you need a 'please wait' dialogue if the operation takes so little time to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug. delay your dismiss long enough with nsthread, or engage in other stupidity to work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do smth that can take much time in the separate thread. Then you can notify main thread(for example, you can set caller as the delegate and send a message after your calculation, or url request, or smth else has been ended) and dismiss your modal view controller there. I use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method if I don't know time of the calculation and want to show animation correctly.

Comment: you are misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: according to the updated info. why cannot you just dismiss your modal viewController with, for example, 1 second delay? I think it will be long enough.

Comment: yes, there are numerous, irritating workarounds. looks like it's just another sdk bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the modal dialog to show information about the stuff you are doing? i.e. is it being used as a Please Wait... If so when you're probably better just showing a please wait dialog over the top of your current view.

Comment: sure, i'd maybe be better off, and it may be easier, but that's not what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found a compromise which works for me. Basically I'm presenting the modal view without animation but dismiss it with animation. Without the animation no animation thread is being started which could cause you any trouble.

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.lvc animated:NO];
//do stuff
```

and later on...

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Still far away from perfect, but maybe it helps.